# How to install the Alamofire 4.0 in Xcode 8.0

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, swift3

I am using the updated Xcode 8.0. How to install the alamofire 4.0 using cocoa pods. i am tried this one https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire. am getting an error when i convert the swift

Comment: This is so vague it’s not answerable. Can you clarify what error you are getting exactly, at which point of your code?

Comment: When i am install the pod and in xcode if i convert am getting an error

Comment: Yes, but what error, on what code? Use the „edit“ link to edit the information into your question.

Comment: Swift Complie error

Comment: But what is the error? Please copy paste it here from Xcode.

Comment: Showing All Errors Only
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Comment: Reinstall again

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'convert the Swift'? Please share some code how you use Alamofire in your project.

Comment: these lines are am giving when am installing the podfile

Comment: pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

Answer (score 11):

Just follow these easy step >>>>>

**1** Open Terminal and Type  **gem install cocoapods**

**2** Create Xcode project and set directory of project in terminal and and write **pod init**

**3** A pod file will created, open it and write this -

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
end
```

**4** Save init file **cmd+S**

**5**  Finally write **pod install**

For complete reference please refer [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/)

Comment: I don’t think he is having problems *installing* Alamofire.

Comment: i was just read the question and Answered.  these comment till not coming.

Comment: am just followed the above steps but am again getting the swift syntax error

Comment: please explain what you want to do

Comment: `I don’t think *She* is having problems installing Alamofire` Indeed! Apologies, @Amutha.

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
end

Comment: Hey **@Amutha** plz share a screenshot of the error.

Comment: am giving these lines to create the podfile.. the podfile is created when am opening the workspace it shows the alert view convert to current convert swift syntax==> then am giving next==> next ==> finally am getting the swift syntax error nearly 800 errors how to overcome this

Comment: May be Some files are showing as Red that mean those file dose't exist in your project. So delete those file and put again

Comment: can u see this link  file:///Users/nanonino14/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-22%20at%204.05.01%20PM.png

Comment: file:///Users/nanonino14/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-22%20at%204.05.01%20PM.png

Comment: No that's not working. You need to add the pictures to your question above, using the icon with the mountain on it.

Comment: Not possible see by us, these file exist in your Machine.  not mine. follow to @Koen

Comment: i guess you using pod --version 1.0.1

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Homely/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'ios8'
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps to install a pod:

1) Open the terminal.

2) Type `pod`

3) You should be able to see usage and commands...

**if (** this is not the case **)** {

Type: `gem install cocoapods`

Follow from Step 4:

**} else {**

Follow from Step 4:

**}**

4) Navigate to the directory of the project in terminal.

5) Now type: `pod init`

This will generate the pod file in your project directory with the respect to your project configuration...If you have enabled the tests, 
UITests...then the pod file will look differently.

6) You need to find these lines:

```
 target 'your project name will come here by default' do

# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for <your project name will come here by default>
  //Add the below line: 
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'<br>
```

7) Now Type: `pod install`

That's it!!!(pod will get installed and you can use the methods you want...!)

Answer (score -1):

## this Version Best Last Version

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.9.1'