# Xcode 7.3.1 update to 8, Swift2 project with cocoapods fall to build

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

one week ago I ran my project with a few pods well on Xcode 7.3.1. But now I have upgraded to Xcode 8. 
When I open the project, it asked me to convert the codes to Swift 3 automatically. If I do not convert, it exists 2 errors in some pods swift file. When I finished converting, it becomes 83 errors!! What should I do to run the project well in Xcode 8? I just use following pods:

```
pod "TextFieldEffects"
pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu'
pod 'LTMorphingLabel'
pod 'Material', '~> 1.0'
```

Comment: Use xcode 7.3 with pods old version file. it should be easy for you.

Comment: @LokeshDudhat I am downloading Xcode 7.3.1 now. But I wonder if there is any solution to run in Xcode 8?

Comment: @user6702783 Have you tried upgrading to Swift 2.3 instead of Swift 3?

Comment: @user6702783 if you have to work with swift 3.0, you need to solve many errors.

Comment: @kennytm It seems that I have not converted to any version. What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616967/xcode-8-swift-update-with-error-use-legacy-swift-language-version/39617917#39617917

Comment: see my answer in this thread. it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Do one Thing -**

Open Terminal and run this command

```
pod update
```

Because currently you are using an old version.

After that if need **pod install** again

Comment: Under the project direction? Do I also need to update the cocoapods?

Comment: Yes, by the way you can just open terminal and run this command

Comment: One of the pod seems not been updated and it exists some errors after I updated, should I convert the file? or convert into swift 2.3?

Comment: read this complete answer, it may helps you - [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636385/how-to-install-the-alamofire-4-0-in-xcode-8-0/39636620?noredirect=1#comment66579750_39636620)

Comment: I also ran "pod install", I believe some pods have been updated, but there are four errors all the same: “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Comment: tell me your installed pod version

Comment: pod --version
1.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124003/discussion-between-ideveloper-and-user6702783).