# How to send data from iOS to MySql database in swift 4

Tags: php, ios, swift

I tried to google it but all the tutorials are in swift 3 or below. All I know is that you have to use a JSONEncoder in swift and have to send the JSON data from swift.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What exactly want to achieve ?

Comment: You can't send JSON directly to MySQL, you need to create some API layer in between. How to do this is too broad for StackOverflow though, you'll need to do some research

Comment: I want to send data from iOS to MySql database using swift 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this link to know how to install Alamofire.

[How to install the Alamofire 4.0 in Xcode 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636385/how-to-install-the-alamofire-4-0-in-xcode-8-0)

Use this code to send your data to server.

```
// https://www.yourAPIHostedWebsite.com/endpoints/
let url = "http://www.example.com/index.html?name=santosh&country=nepal"

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
}.resume()
```

Now you need a code in your server to store datas. Here a very simple code which gets value. I hope you know how to store data to Mysql database on server side. If not [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) might be helpful to start.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["name"];
$country = $_GET["country"];

if($name || $country) {
// Now store these values to your database. 
}
?>
```